# Edit Mode Wireframe + Translucent View?

Tags: texturing, wireframe, edit-mode

I'm trying to texture a model I made with a texture pallet I imported into the *Compositing View* with *Smart UV Unwrap*, but when I'm in *Edit Mode*, the entire model is in a sort of mid-way-to *Wireframe View* in which everything is grey but still see-through and selectable through. When I key <kbd>Z</kbd> to toggle to wireframe, the grayness goes away and my model is simply shown in regular wireframe. From YouTube tutorials, I see no one with this issue. Please help!

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to clarify?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're talking about something like the following.

[image]

This is enabled by the *Limit Selection to Visible* button at the bottom of the *3D Viewport* ([image]). Clicking it will toggle the transparency.

[image]